# Authentication cookie is not kept between pages

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have a .net core web application devided in some modules.

For simplicity, I tell you that I have only 2 modules. The entry point module and the authentication module. Entry point module, is accessed, for example, with `https://localhost:1234/` or `https://localhost:1234/Home/Index`, while authentication module adds a `Authenticate` prefix, this way: `https://localhost:1234/Authenticate/Security/Login`.

`https://localhost:1234/Authenticate/Security/Login` shows the authentication form. When authentication is performed successfully, `https://localhost:1234/` is loaded. When that occurs, and by debugging, I checked that `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false. However, if I load `https://localhost:1234/Authenticate/Security/Login`, I checked that `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is true and all other identity data are present. If I load `https://localhost:1234/` again, `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is shown as false again.

It seems the authentication cookie is associated to the `Authenticate` module assembly, and not with any module in the same domain.

This is the cookie configuration:

```
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "MySecurity";
            options.LoginPath = "/Authenticate/Security/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Authenticate/Security/Logout";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Authenticate/Security/AccessDenied";
            options.ReturnUrlParameter = "ReturnUrl";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
```

I have tried using other properties such as `options.Cookie.Domain` and `options.Cookie.SameSite`as well but no avail.

How can I configure the cookie for this scenario?

Regards

Jaime

Comment: Also ,you should check if cookie exists within your browser with the following steps:F12--Application--Cookie,not simply  juding with User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

Comment: the cookie  configuration you provided doesn't have a direct relationship with  the issue,please provide a minimal example that could repo

Comment: @RuikaiFeng according to your F12 suggestion I saw that when the cookie is created, there is a Path associated. In this case `/Authenticate`. I added `options.Cookie.Path = "/";` to the cookie configuration and the problem is gone. Thanks :-)